# Alfresco - Error 403 with PUT or DELETE http calls

Tags: angular, http, tomcat, alfresco, http-status-code-403

I've installed Alfresco Community 7.3 with docker, and I'm developing a frontend application with Angular.

It use a Tomcat webserver. When I try to execute a PUT or DELETE http call, server send back the following error: **"status: 403, statusText: 'Forbidden"**.

The routine is the following (eg. for delete a document):

```
sAlfEliminaFile(ticket: string, idFile: string){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(ticket),
    });

    return this.http.delete('/alfrescoapi/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/22f98143-eb5e-48f0-8c40-4534c1fe73d1', {headers : headers })
  }
```

I'm using a proxy to avoid CORS problem, with following parameters:

```
{
    "/alfrescoapi": {
      "target": "http://localhost/alfresco",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/alfrescoapi": "/api"
      },
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

I've already tried to change the param "changeOrigin" to false but it does not work.
Credentials are corrects, I've also tried with admin credentials, with the same result.

What I can do to solve?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try make calls via Api Explorer? It return same response? <our_alfresco_ip>/api-explorer/

Comment: From Api Explorer, it works!
I also tried with am API application tester like Postman and it doesn't work.

Comment: Then must be problem somewhere in connection or way how you call endpoint. Other method (GET or POST) works?

Comment: I think to have found the problem. The NGINX proxy does not allow DELETE and PUT call.
Do you have some idea to solve?